# Passing environment variables over ssh for remote expansion

Tags: shell, ssh

I am trying to pass an environment variable to my shell script, and then echo out what I passed in. In this example $HOME is an environment variable already set.

`./my_script.ksh $HOME`

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
my_var=${1}
echo "You sent: ${my_var}"
```

I want my output to be `You sent: $HOME` but instead it is evaluating it and is producing `You Sent: /home/blah/usr`

The point of this is that I plan on doing an SSH command that I need to pass $my_var too un-evaluated (aka be $HOME) because $HOME across each server is a different value and for the SSH command I want it to use the value from the server it is SSH'ing too. so was hoping to just pass it in so during the SSH it would evaluate correctly

Here is an example of what I want to have happen. Let's assume $HOME is already set on Server1 and Server2 like:

```
Server1 $HOME: /home/blah/usr
Server2 $HOME: /home/superblah/newusr
```

From Server1 execute `my_script.ksh $HOME`

The script is the same as above with one extra line of:

```
ssh my_user@Server2 "echo Server got: $my_var"
```

What my output currently is:

```
You sent: /home/blah/usr
Server got: /home/blah/usr
```

What I want is just that ssh command to produce:

```
Server got: /home/superblah/newusr
```

Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, [your **real** question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400222/use-remote-environment-variables-value-in-scp-path) involving SCP instead of SSH is a very pertinent difference.

Comment: Also, using `$HOME` is somewhat misleading -- it lends itself to answers that rely on the default remote directory when a SCP or SSH connection is made being $HOME, whereas your real use case requires something more involved.

Comment: BTW, I'm writing code here for ksh93 -- if you were switching to bash you'd want to replace `foo=$(printf '%q ' ...)` with `printf -v foo '%q ' ...`, but not much else would change. On the other hand, if you're using some 3rd-party clone of ksh rather than the real thing, my first advice is to switch -- either to real ksh (if you want something fast, featureful and stable) or bash (for something not so fast, but actively-maintained -- and in current 4.x, pretty darned close on features even if the syntax differs).

Comment: BTW, do I correctly see not a single accepted answer anywhere in your history? Accepting answers (if they work) is an essential part of the workflow here -- it's how we determine whether an issue has been acceptably resolved or still requires more attention; also, accepting an answer provides a nominal (+2) rep bonus for the person asking the associated question.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent resolving the variable by wrap it in single quotes

```
./my_script.ksh '$HOME'
```

I tried it like this:

```
[host1]$ echo $HOME
/home/user1
[host1]$ ssh user2@host2 echo '$HOME'
/home/user2
[host1]$
```

Comment: The OP has edited their question, asking for remote evaluation rather than just literal transmission. (I believe their *real* question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400222/use-remote-environment-variables-value-in-scp-path, which they also asked slightly earlier).

Comment: ...of course, doing remote evaluation *safely* -- without the security risks associated with `eval` -- means doing some work.

Answer (score 0):

`envsubst` can be used to substitute strings of the form `$HOME` or `$foo` with the value of like-named environment variables. Thus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
my_var=$1
my_var_subst=$(envsubst <<<"$my_var")
echo "You sent: ${my_var}"
echo "Interpreted as: ${my_var_subst}"
```

...will emit:

```
You sent: $HOME
Interpreted as: /home/superblah/newusr
```

when invoked with `./myscript '$HOME'`.

---

Note that one needs to be careful when passing values over SSH, as SSH implicitly runs `sh -c "$*"` with the arguments passed -- concatenating them together with whitespace and evaluating that single string as a shell command. Thus, running your command over ssh may look like:

```
ssh somehost $'./myscript \'$HOME\''
```

...or...

```
ssh somehost "./myscript \$HOME"
```

...or, to make it easier, let the shell do the escaping work for you:

```
remote_command=$(printf '%q ' ./myscript '$HOME')
ssh somehost "$remote_command"
```